# How can I force separate elements within a "td" element of an html table to display inline (left to right)?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms, css-tables

I am updating an old ASP.NET Web Forms app, which my group previously only supported on IE, to be compatible with modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc.). Among other issues, I'm having a small problem with the way icons (which happen to also be links) are displayed within a single 'td' element of a certain table generated when the app loads up. The icons are links to various options related to each entry/row of the table.

On IE, the icons are arranged inline, from left to right.  But on other browsers, the icons are stacked vertically.  I was told to make the style consistent with how it looked in IE.

I thought this would be a simple matter of changing some CSS, but so far I haven't been able to get that to work. The icons I'm talking about are children of  elements, and are either  elements or 's (which then have img children of their own), so I tried

```
td img {
display: inline-block;
}

td a {
display: inline-block;
}
```

but this had no effect at all.

The html (once it's generated) is structure like

```
(within table, body, row...)

<td>
 <img src="icon1.gif">
 <a href=JavaScript:editThisEntry(entryNumber)>
    <img src="icon2.gif">
 </a>
 <a href=JavaScript:doADifferentEdit(entryNumber)>
    <img src="icon3.gif">
 </a>
</td>
```

So, expected result: three icons within a  element are lined up in a row (and the td is wide enough to accommodate).

Actual: three icons with a  are stacked on top of each other, making each row "fat" from top to bottom and throwing off the look of the table.

I'm pretty new to this stuff, so I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I didn't find a description of my exact issue through Google. Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you try `flex`? Also could you provide us jsfiddle or something to see the problem.

Comment: it's probably wrapping... try: <td nowrap="">

Comment: As above, probably some css on the td is required.

Comment: Thank you, all!  Adding <td nowrap=""> in the inspector worked, so I just looked up the CSS equivalent of that and added it to my style sheet.  See solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. Good suggestions. Ultimately, pcalkins' response worked for me, but I had to tweak it slightly to add it into my CSS stylesheet.  I ended up using this:

```
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td a, td img {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

td { display: flex; }

Would probably be the best solution since it will apply in modern browsers but isn't supported in IE until IE 11.